'YOLO' object has no attribute 'YOLOv8'
# Veri kümenizin yolunu ayarlayın
data_dir = '/content/datasets/u-granada-g-detect-2'

# Sınıf etiketlerini yükleyin
class_names = ['knife', 'gun']

# Eğitim ve doğrulama veri kümelerini oluşturun
train_images = []
train_targets = []
val_images = []
val_targets = []

for phase in ['train', 'valid']:
    image_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, phase, 'images')
    label_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, phase, 'labels')

    for image_path in tqdm(os.listdir(image_dir)):
        image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_dir, image_path))
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        label_path = os.path.join(label_dir, image_path.replace('.jpg', '.txt'))
        with open(label_path, 'r') as f:
            labels = []
            for line in f:
                bbox = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
                labels.append([int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]), int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3]), 1 if bbox[4] == 0 else 0])

        train_images.append(image)
        train_targets.append(labels)

        if phase == 'val':
            val_images.append(image)
            val_targets.append(labels)

# Yeniden boyutlandırma işlemi
resized_train_images = [cv2.resize(img, (224, 224)) for img in train_images]
resized_val_images = [cv2.resize(img, (224, 224)) for img in val_images]

# NumPy dizisine dönüştürme
train_images = np.array(resized_train_images)
val_images = np.array(resized_val_images)

# Normalleştirme işlemi
train_images = train_images / 255.0
val_images = val_images / 255.0

# EfficientNet B4 modelini yükleyin
efficientnet = EfficientNet.from_name('efficientnet-b4')

# YOLOv8n modelini oluşturun
yolo_model = model.YOLOv8(cfg='yolov8x.yaml')

# Modeli EfficientNet B4 omurgası ile değiştirin
yolo_model.model.backbone = efficientnet

# Eğitim ve doğrulama veri kümelerini ayarlayın
train_dataset = torch.utils.data.Dataset(train_images, train_targets)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
val_dataset = torch.utils.data.Dataset(val_images, val_targets)
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=False)

# Eğitim ayarlarını belirleyin
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(yolo_model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Modeli eğitin
for epoch in range(100):
    # Her epoch için eğitim ve doğrulama aşamaları
    for images, targets in tqdm(train_loader):
        images = images.to(device)
        targets = [target.to(device) for target in targets]

        # Tahminleri hesaplayın ve kaybı hesaplayın
        outputs = yolo_model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs[0], targets[0])

        # Geri yayılım ve parametreleri güncelleyin
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    # Doğrulama setinde performansı değerlendirin
    with torch.no_grad():
        total_correct = 0
        total_samples = 0
        for images, targets in tqdm(val_loader):
            images = images.to(device)
        targets = [target.to(device) for target in targets]

        # Tahminleri hesaplayın
        outputs = yolo_model(images)
        predictions = torch.argmax(outputs[0], dim=1)

        # Doğru tahminleri sayın
        for i, (prediction, target) in enumerate(zip(predictions, targets)):
            total_samples += 1
            if prediction == target:
                total_correct += 1

        # Doğrulama doğruluğunu hesaplayın
        accuracy = total_correct / total_samples
        print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}: Val Accuracy: {accuracy:.4f}')

# Eğitim tamamlandıktan sonra modeli kaydedin
torch.save(yolo_model, 'yolov8_knife_gun_detector.pth')

print('Model successfully trained and saved!')

How can i fix this error?
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-500f42116361> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 
      4 # YOLOv8n modelini oluşturun
----> 5 yolo_model = model.YOLOv8(cfg='yolov8x.yaml')
      6 
      7 # Modeli EfficientNet B4 omurgası ile değiştirin

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   1686             if name in modules:
   1687                 return modules[name]
-> 1688         raise AttributeError(f"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{name}'")
   1689 
   1690     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Union[Tensor, 'Module']) -> None:

AttributeError: 'YOLO' object has no attribute 'YOLOv8'


Where is this model object initialized: yolo_model = model.YOLOv8(cfg='yolov8x.yaml')? Please change the code to a minimal reproducible example, so others can better understand the problem.

It's nothing more than a syntax error. The code should be the following on the faulty line :
yolo_model = model.YOLO(cfg='yolov8x.yaml')

Instead of your
yolo_model = model.YOLOv8(cfg='yolov8x.yaml')


This time i got AttributeError: 'YOLO' object has no attribute 'YOLO'

Then the problem might come from the fact that your model weights yolov8x.yaml are not in the right directory, therefore not seen by the ultralytics library.
